# ZendFramework XML Routing not working

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework-modules

**Problem:** I see Blank Page

**All I want** to do is when I type

http://localhost --> Go to modules/default/index

http://localhost/admin --> Go to modules/admin/index

index.php has not important. Common settings

**Folder Structure**

[image]

**Bootstrap.php**

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initRoutes()
    {
        $front  = $this->getResource('frontcontroller');
        $router = $front->getRouter();
        $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/routes.xml');
        $router->addConfig($config->routes);

    }
}
```

**application.ini**

```
[production]

;Debug output
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0

;Include path
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"

;Bootstrap
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"

;NameSpace
appnamespace = "Application"

;Front Controller
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

;Modular suport
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] =

;resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = "1"
;resources.frontController.defaultModule = "default"

;Views
resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
resources.view.basePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/"
;resources.view.doctype = "XHTML1_STRICT" 
resources.view.doctype = "XHTML1_TRANSITIONAL"
```

**Config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<router>
    <routes>
        <some-action>
            <type>Zend_Controller_Router_Route</type>
            <route>:module/:controller</route>
            <defaults>
                <controller>index</controller>
                <action>index</action>
            </defaults>
        </some-action>
    </routes>
</router>
```

**default controller**

```
<?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // action body
    }


}
```

**admin controller**

```
<?php

class Admin_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // action body
    }


}
```

**.htaccess**

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

**ERROR:**

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Loader\Autoloader.php on line 380

Comment: please turn on exceptions, and post the error

Comment: @ArneRie , Attached error at end of question

Answer (score 0):

I think you **doesn't** need an Router Configuration for this case? This is the standard behavoir of Zend Framework.

Iam not sure in the moment, but try to Prefix your IndexController with "Default_":

```
class Default_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

}
```

If this is not working, please post your ReWrite Rule.

Comment: not working with the above changes. Added rewrite rules at the end of question.

Answer (score 0):

try it with the following xml for your routes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<router>
    <routes>
        <front>
            <route>/</route>
            <defaults>
                <module>default</module>
                <controller>index</controller>
                <action>index</action>
            </defaults>
        </front>
        <admin>
            <route>/admin</route>
            <defaults>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>index</controller>
                <action>index</action>
            </defaults>
        </admin>
    </routes>
</router>
```